# Computer Vision video frames result on react with django

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, opencv, django-rest-framework, computer-vision

I want to show image frames generated from OpenCV on react, I am using Django as server-side. I get a single frame from each request when I send requests from react to Django, so it constitutes a large number of requests at a time.

For now, I am just sending a request to API again and again which I think is not a proper way. I need resources like a tutorial , articles to learn the best way to achieve this thing.

I have seen like WebSockets will be good but I researched a lot but can't found a proper resource.

Can someone suggest to me or can share a good resource to learn?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge of react. But if I were to do the same task on a webpage then I would read images/frames from webcam using javascript. 
Here is an example of it:
[Read image from webcam using javascript](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm).

After retrieving the image, you could send frames from js to Django and perform the OpenCV task there.